# How can I calculate the multinomial probability values?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write a function that finds the multinomial expansion. In order to do that I modified the binomial probability function;

From:

f(n, k, p) = n! / (k! * (n - k)!) * p<sup>k</sup> * (1 - p)<sup>(n - k)</sup>

To:

f(n, k, p) = n! / (k[0]! * k[1]! * ... * k[x]!) * p[0]<sup>k[0]</sup> * p[1]<sup>k[1]</sup> * ... p[x]<sup>k[x]</sup>

The codes are:

```py
from math import prod


def factorial(n: int) -> int:
    r = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        r *= i
    return r


def combination(n: int, k: list) -> float:
    return factorial(n) / prod(map(factorial, k))


def multinomial_probability(n: int, k: list, p: list) -> float:
    return combination(n, k) * prod(map(pow, p, k))
```

To get `the coefficients of binomial expansion`, I am calling the `multinomial_probability` function with the following arguments:

```py
for n in range(5):
    print([multinomial_probability(n=n, k=[k, n - k], p=[1/2, 1/2]) for k in range(n + 1)])
```

The result I get is below and it's the correct result:

```py
[1.0]
[0.5, 0.5]
[0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
[0.125, 0.375, 0.375, 0.125]
[0.0625, 0.25, 0.375, 0.25, 0.0625]
```

Now I am thinking how to find `the coefficients of the trinomial expansion`.

In order to do that, I called the `multinomial_probability` function with the following arguments, despite I knew that it was not going to give me the correct result.

```py
for n in range(5):
    print([multinomial_probability(n=n, k=[m, k - m, n - k], p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]) for k in range(n + 1) for m in range(k + 1)])
```

The above code printed the following result:

```py
[1.0]
[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]
[0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.2222222222222222, 0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.1111111111111111]
[0.03703703703703703, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.1111111111111111, 0.03703703703703703, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1111111111111111, 0.03703703703703703]
[0.012345679012345677, 0.0493827160493827, 0.0493827160493827, 0.07407407407407407, 0.14814814814814814, 0.07407407407407407, 0.0493827160493827, 0.14814814814814814, 0.14814814814814814, 0.0493827160493827, 0.012345679012345677, 0.0493827160493827, 0.07407407407407407, 0.0493827160493827, 0.012345679012345677]
```

The number of elements of the lists I would like to get are 1, 3, 5, 9, 11 in order. The code I wrote produces lists with element numbers of 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, and the probabilities are calculated according to the number of elements of these lists.

So the code I wrote produces lists with element numbers of 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, and the probabilities are calculated according to the number of elements of these lists. We can't give decimal numbers to k or m either. Multiplying two `int`s does not yield 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 in order.

Now, I am changing the code as below:

```py
desired_outputs = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
for n in range(5):
    print([multinomial_probability(n=n, k=[k, n - 2 * k, k], p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]) for k in range(desired_outputs[n])])
```

The output I get is like this:

```
[1.0]
[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.08333333333333334]
[0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.055555555555555566, 0.006172839506172837, 0.00038580246913580245]
[0.03703703703703703, 0.2222222222222222, 0.05555555555555555, 0.0061728395061728366, 0.00038580246913580234, 1.5432098765432092e-05, 4.286694101508915e-07]
[0.012345679012345677, 0.14814814814814814, 0.07407407407407407, 0.008230452674897117, 0.0005144032921810698, 2.0576131687242793e-05, 5.71559213534522e-07, 1.166447374560249e-08, 1.8225740227503888e-10]
```

This is not correct either.

I change `k` like this:

```py
desired_outputs = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
for n in range(5):
    print([multinomial_probability(n=n, k=[k, n - k - 1, 1], p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]) for k in range(desired_outputs[n])])
```

And this produces the following output:

```py
[1.0]
[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666669]
[0.2222222222222222, 0.2222222222222222, 0.1111111111111111, 0.037037037037037035, 0.009259259259259257]
[0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.1111111111111111, 0.03703703703703703, 0.009259259259259259, 0.001851851851851851, 0.0003086419753086419]
[0.0493827160493827, 0.14814814814814814, 0.14814814814814814, 0.0493827160493827, 0.012345679012345677, 0.0024691358024691353, 0.0004115226337448558, 5.878894767783656e-05, 7.348618459729569e-06]
```

What kind of change I should make in order to get the coefficients of the following output (trinomial expansion)?

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I strongly encourage you to avoid long one-line expressions. In particular, try to avoid `lambda` and `:=`. They are useful in some situations, but you use them too much in situations where they are really not needed. It will make the code more readable. In particular, a line like `return factorial(n) / f(k) if (f := lambda x: factorial(x[0]) * f(x[1:]) if x else 1) else 1` is incredibly hard to read.

Comment: I think you could avoid this function `f` entirely and write `return factorial(n) / prod(map(factorial, x))` where `prod` is `from math import prod`.

Comment: Likewise, instead of the very-hard-to-read `return (combination(n, k) * f(p, k) if (f := lambda x, y: x[0] ** y[0] * f(x[1:], y[1:]) if x and y else 1) else 1)`, you could write `return combination(n, k) * prod(map(pow, p, k))`

Comment: Ok, I changed the functions. Thank you. By the way, can you help me with the question?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question exactly

Comment: [Note that `pow` is a builtin function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) You don't need to import it. You can just use `pow` directly.

Comment: I can get the coefficients of the  `binomial expansion` correctly.  That is, when we open the expression (a + b)^23, we can find out how many terms there will be and what their coefficients will be. But how do we calculate the coefficients and the number of terms when we make the expansion in trinomial or tetranomial rather than binomial. I'm trying to find this.

Comment: Naturally I would do `import sympy; a, b, c = sympy.symbols('a b c'); print(((a+b+c)**23).expand())`. But you might consider that cheating :-p

Comment: :) Yes. I am trying to find an algorithm to do that.

Comment: I understand what is `k` in your functions, but what is `p`?

Comment: `p`'s are the probabilities. For binomial expansion we use `[1/2, 1/2]` or `[1/3, 2/3]`. The sum of `p` should be 1. For trinomial expansion I wrote `[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]`. So `p[0]` is for `k[0]`, `p[1]` is for `k[1]` and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a function `partitions(n, d)` to find all the ways to divide a power `n` onto `d` variables.

Then you can calculate `multicomb(n, k)` for each `k in partitions(n, d)`

```py
from math import prod, factorial
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet
from typing import Iterator

def multicomb(n: int, k: list) -> int:
    '''assume sum(k) == n'''
    return factorial(n) // prod(map(factorial, k))

def diff(k: list) -> tuple:
    '''un-cumsum a list of cumulative sums'''
    result = []
    c = 0
    for x in k:
        result.append(x - c)
        c = x
    return tuple(result)

def partitions(n: int, d: int) -> Iterator[int]:
    for k in combinations_with_replacement(range(n+1), d-1):
        yield diff(k+(n,))

def prettyfactor(c: int) -> str:
    return str(c) if c != 1 else ''

def prettyvar(xi: int, ki: int) -> str:
    if ki == 0:
        return ''
    elif ki == 1:
        return str(xi)
    else:
        return f'{xi}**{ki}'

def product_expansion(n: int, d: int) -> str:
    variables = alphabet[:d] # assume d <= 26
    return ' + '.join(
        prettyfactor(multicomb(n,k)) + ' ' + ' '.join(prettyvar(xi,ki) for xi,ki in zip(variables, k))
        for k in partitions(n, d)
    )
```

```py
print(product_expansion(2, 2)) # (a + b)**2
  b**2 + 2 a b +  a**2 

print(product_expansion(3, 2)) # (a + b)**3
  b**3 + 3 a b**2 + 3 a**2 b +  a**3 

print(product_expansion(2, 3)) # (a + b + c)**2
   c**2 + 2  b c +   b**2  + 2 a  c + 2 a b  +  a**2  

print(product_expansion(3, 3)) # (a + b + c)**3
   c**3 + 3  b c**2 + 3  b**2 c +   b**3  + 3 a  c**2 + 6 a b c + 3 a b**2  + 3 a**2  c + 3 a**2 b  +  a**3
```

I wrote function `product_expansion` to return a string representing the expanded product `(a + b + c + ...)**n`.

Instead we can go back to your probabilities question. We want to return the probability of each possible combination. An appropriate return value is a `dict`, mapping combinations to probabilities.

```py
def weighted_dice_probabilities(n: int, p: list) -> dict:
    '''roll n identical weighted dice
    face i has probability p[i]
    return a dict mapping each possible outcome to its proba'''
    d = len(p)
    return {
        k: multicomb(n, k) * prod(map(pow, p, k))
        for k in partitions(n, d)
    }

print(weighted_dice_probabilities(0, [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]))
{(0, 0, 0): 1.0}
# roll no die, get no result with probability 1

print(weighted_dice_probabilities(1, [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]))
{(0, 0, 1): 0.3333, (0, 1, 0): 0.3333, (1, 0, 0): 0.3333}
# roll 1 die, get each face with probability 1/3

print(weighted_dice_probabilities(2, [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]))
{(0, 0, 2): 0.1111, (0, 1, 1): 0.2222, (0, 2, 0): 0.1111,
 (1, 0, 1): 0.2222, (1, 1, 0): 0.2222, (2, 0, 0): 0.1111}
# roll 2 dice, get each couple of faces with proba 2/9 or each pair with proba 1/9

print(weighted_dice_probabilities(3, [1/3, 1/3, 1/3]))
{(0, 0, 3): 0.037037, (0, 1, 2): 0.111111, (0, 2, 1): 0.111111, (0, 3, 0): 0.037037,
 (1, 0, 2): 0.111111, (1, 1, 1): 0.222222, (1, 2, 0): 0.111111,
 (2, 0, 1): 0.111111, (2, 1, 0): 0.111111, (3, 0, 0): 0.037037}
# roll 3 dice, get each triple with proba 1/27, or each one-face-plus-a-pair with proba 1/9, or get three distinct faces with proba 2/9.
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try to understand the code you wrote.

Comment: If you have any questions do not hesitate to ask!

Comment: I'll look into the topic better when I'm free. If I have any questions, I will ask them. Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: Unfortunately the last code you wrote, `probadict` produces the same output. Run this using the code I provided: `for n in range(5): print([multinomial_probability(n=n, k=[m, k - m, n - k], p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]) for k in range(n + 1) for m in range(k + 1)])`
  you will see the output is same.

Comment: And I had written this: The number of elements of the lists I would like to get are 1, 3, 5, 9, 11 in order. The code I wrote produces lists with element numbers of 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, and the probabilities are calculated according to the number of elements of these lists.

So the code I wrote produces lists with element numbers of 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, and the probabilities are calculated according to the number of elements of these lists. We can't give decimal numbers to k or m either. Multiplying two ints does not yield 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 in order.

Comment: @dildeolupbiten I don't understand what 1,3,5,9,11 are supposed to represent?

Comment: @dildeolupbiten If you have three balls in an urn, one red one blue one green, and you pick a ball uniformly at random, put it back, pick again, put it back, pick again, then the probability to get 3 times the blue ball is 1/27 = 0.037037...; and the proba to get 1 time red 2 times blue is 1/9 = 0.111111..., which is why the dict contains `(0,3,0): 0.037037...` and `(1, 2, 0): 0.111111...`.

Comment: @dildeolupbiten So, my code correctly produced the correct probabilities for the probability question that I asked. If you wanted different probabilities, then you are asking something different, and I don't understand what.

Comment: @dildeolupbiten I have renamed `probadict` into `weighted_dice_probabilities` and added comments to make it more clear what is being calculated.

Comment: Thank you @Stef <3, I understood better while working on it. And you were right. I am accepting your answer as the correct answer. By the way I implemented a different method, you can check it out in the next message.

Answer (score 1):

@Stef

Here is the algorithm I followed:

```py
from math import prod


def factorial(n: int) -> int:
    r = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        r *= i
    return r


def combination(n: int, k: list) -> float:
    return factorial(n) / prod(map(factorial, k))


def multinomial_probability(n: int, k: list, p: list) -> float:
    return combination(n, k) * prod(map(pow, p, k))


def product(n: int, r: int) -> list:
    return [[i, *p] for i in range(n + 1) for p in product(n, r - 1)] if r else [[]]


def k_values(n: int, r: int) -> list:
    return [i for i in product(n, r) if sum(i) == n]


for n in range(5):
    print([multinomial_probability(n=n, k=k, p=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]) for k in k_values(n, 3)])
```

Comment: Awesome. Since you imported `math.prod`, you can also shorten `factorial` to `def factorial(n): return prod(range(n+1))`. Also your function `product` is very similar to [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). More precisely, we should have the equality `product(n, r) == list(itertools.product(range(n+1), repeat=r))` for all n and r.

Comment: Also note your function `k_values` relies on filtering out bad combinations from all combinations generated by `product(n, r)`. An interesting question is: which fraction of the generated combinations are we throwing out? `product(n, r)` will generate a total of `(n+1)**r` combinations, among which only `(r+n-1 choose n)` are good combinations. See [Wikipedia: Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) for an explanation.

Comment: `k_values` function is filtering the combinations that are possible to occur. Other elements of the product have no possibility to occur in such a distribution, no? What are the results you get when you run this code: `for n in range(5): print(k_values(n=n, r=2))` or this code:  `for n in range(5): print(k_values(n=n, r=3))` ?

Comment: Yes, your function `k_values` gives the correct result. My remark was about efficiency not correctness. First `k_values` calls `product(n, r)` which produces a lot of combinations; then the bad combinations are filtered out and the good combinations are kept. So the question is, how many bad combinations were generated by `product(n, r)`?

Comment: The `math.prod` function is sometimes useful, but not very often. Instead, function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is much more often useful. Unless you do a lot of combinatorics. If you do a lot of combinatorics, you might be interested in functions from third-party library sympy. See for instance: [sympy.functions.combinatorial](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/combinatorial.html)

Comment: If you manipulate arrays of numbers a lot, especially floats, you might also be interested in numpy. For instance, see how I wrote `map(pow, p, k)` in my answer. If `p` and `k` are numpy arrays, then you can write directly `p**k` instead, which is easier to write and read for the programmer, *and* also faster to execute for the computer.

Comment: You are right, in order to get the correct 100 values of k, product is producing 10000 combinations. It's not an efficient way yes. `for i in range(100): print(len(product(n=i, r=2)), len(k_values(n=i, r=2)))`

Comment: What do you think about the algorithm of the `k_values` that we see in the next message?

Answer (score 0):

@Stef, what do you think about this algorithm?

```py
def k_values(n: int, r: int):
    length = r

    def filtered_product(_n, _r):
        return (
            [
                v for i in range(_n + 1) for c in filtered_product(_n, _r - 1)
                if (v := [i, *c]) and (sum(v) == _n if len(v) == length else True)
            ]
            if _r else [[]]
        )

    return filtered_product(n, r)
```

Comment: Note that `for c in filtered_product(_n, _r-1) for i in range(_n+1)` would be much more efficient than `for i in range(_n+1) for c in filtered_product(_n, _r-1)` (python's syntax for nested for-loops in list comprehensions is counterintuitive)

Comment: Condition `sum(v) == _n if len(v) == length else True` is equivalent to `len(v) != length or sum(v) == _n`

Comment: You can rewrite `[v for i in ... for c in ... if (v := [i, *c]) and (sum(v) == _n if len(v) == length else True)]` into `[v for c in ... for i in ... if len(v:=[i, *c]) != length or sum(v) == n_]` (I really really dislike using a dummy condition to sneak `:=`)

Comment: Also, since `_r` is decreased by 1 at each recursive call, I think you can test `_r > 0` instead of `len(v) != length`? In which case you don't need to remember `length`, so you can avoid the auxiliary function and make `k_values` a recursive function directly.

Comment: Did you test this new function? Is it correct? I think it should be `filtered_product(_n - i, _r - 1)` in the recursive call, not `filtered_product(_n, _r - 1)`

Comment: Ok, I tried to implement your suggestions @Stef. Can you check the next post please?

Answer (score 0):

@Stef
How is the code now?

Note: By the way, the function should be `f(n, r - 1)`, not `f(n - i, r - 1)`.

In the meanwhile, I am thankful to you a lot.

```py
def k_values(n, r, stop: int = 0):
    return (
        [
            v for k in k_values(n, r - 1, stop + 1) for i in range(n + 1)
            if len(v := [i, *k]) != r + stop or sum(v) == n
        ]
        if r else [[]]
    )
```